# Permanent shared url in box api

Tags: box-api

**My requirement**

One user uploads the file to box from my application using API and other users should be able to see that file as a link in my application.

Im not getting the shared url at the time of upload. And from the document, I understood that the shared url expires soon. Is it possible to get a permanent url to access file by other users (without login to box) ?

Answer (score 1):

Shared links aren't automatically created when you upload a file. You need to make a request to the API to create one. You can find the documentation for how to do that here - https://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file.

If you set the `access` field to `open` and leave the `unshared_at` time empty, then you'll get a link that anyone can access and that won't expire.

For example, your request might look like:

```
PUT https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID

{ "shared_link": { "access": "open" } }
```

and then you'll get a response containing the created link:

```
{
    ...

    "shared_link": {
        "url": "https://www.box.com/s/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul",
        "download_url": "https://www.box.com/shared/static/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul.jpeg",
        "vanity_url": null,
        "is_password_enabled": false,
        "unshared_at": null,
        "download_count": 0,
        "preview_count": 0,
        "access": "open",
        "permissions": {
            "can_download": true,
            "can_preview": true
        }
    }
}
```